# Issue with creating string for values in drop down

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function that makes a Web Api call and returns the data.  I am trying to get the 2 properties of the value returned but am having issues with how to assign the quotes.

```
    function populateNext(nextDD, nextLbl, apiCall, nextDDText, nextDDVal) {
        $.getJSON("api/" + apiCall + "/" + facility_id)
        .done(function (data) {

        var s = '<option value="-1"></option>'; 


        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            s += '<option value="' + val.plan_code + '">' + val.plan_code + '</option>';
        });
            $("#" + nextDD).html(s);
        });
    }
```

The first below line works but how would I change it so that it accepts the values passed in from the function (nextDDVal and nextDDText)?

Works:

```
s += '<option value="' + val.plan_code + '">' + val.plan_code + '</option>';
```

What I'm trying to make work:

```
s += '<option value="' + val. + nextDDVal + '">' + val. + nextDDText + '</option>';
```

Comment: I think you’re looking for this syntax: `val[nextDDVal]`

Comment: It should be val.plan_code and val.plan_code

Comment: That was it.  Thank you! @MTCoster